# Crypto#encrypt giving wrong output for same key and value

Tags: java, encryption, playframework, cryptography, playframework-2.4

I am trying to encrypt decrypt data in play 2.4 .In 2.3 I would simply do

```
Crypto.encryptAES("value","key");
```

but for 2.4 If I am not wrong I would do

```
 Crypto crypto = play.Play.application().injector().instanceOf(Crypto.class);

 Logger.info(crypto.encryptAES("test","olololololololol")+" ----- " + crypto.encryptAES("test","olololololololol"));
```

But for 2.4 its giving

```
2-D0rwUAokm3+Gq1/VEZr92YpTsMU= ----- 2-ARgxqa3fo/7tUI0NMO0LFZYsN5o=
```

different o/p for same key value. Why it is doing that why not same value returned? Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is fine. Play 2.4 uses a different algorith to encrypt data that randomizes some things. You can find more info [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24#Crypto-APIs)

Note that this can still read encrypted data from Play 2.3 (and lower probably).

Comment: thanks for response. Can you show me the sample code to generate the same encryption value? I have tried above but dint get the o/p

Comment: @codegasmer Have you tried to just copy the old class and use it, as stated in that link?

Comment: I am new to scala  and the code is in scala. I copied the Crypto.scala but its giving me the error `play is not an enclosing class
` line 32

Comment: Maybe you forgot to change the `package` entry?